# Why second insert gives me table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS home (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;

INSERT INTO home
(description)
VALUES('home1');

INSERT INTO home (description) VALUES('home2');
```

I need to insert two value in home table.I create table but after second insert it gives me that table doesn't exists? Anyone can help me?

Comment: I actually do not have a problem with your original query. Can you give me a bit more detail over what you're doing. Is this is a program? MySQL Workbench? Or something different?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WNuDSxt

Comment: @poopp . . . Your code works fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cce5d/1.